# Number of files in a directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, find

I'm try to find, in only one row, the number of files (*.rar) in a directory.

For doing this I'm using the commands:

> ```
> for /f "delims=" %i in ('find /c ".rar" "D:\backup e ckpdb ept-icd\test\unload\lista_files_rar.txt"') do echo %i
> ```

but the value of %i I have at the end is : D:\BACKUP E CKPDB EPT-ICD\TEST\UNLOAD\LISTA_FILES_RAR.TXT: 8

I would like to obtain only the number 8 so instead to echo the value I would assign the value to a variable.

I use the command line : dir /b *.rar | find /c ".rar"
that it returns the value of rar files in  the directory, but I can't assign the value to a variable, for example: dir /b *.rar | find /c ".rar" | set/a files =

I tried also to use the keyword tokens=2 but it doesn't work

p.s If it possible to do it only with the find command is also better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [here](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html) for example on counting files

Or you can simply do something like this (not tested)

```
for /F %%j in ('dir /B *.rar ^| find /C /V ""') do set count=%%j
```

Answer (score 0):

This returns just the number; there might be a cleaner way to do it, but unfortuantly "find" can't take it's input from a pipe (i.e., I can't do `dir | find`):

```
@echo off
dir /b *.rar> out.tmp
for /f "usebackq tokens=3" %%i in (`find /c "rar" out.tmp`) do echo %%i
del out.tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

Try "delims=: tokens=3"

You normally will have two colons in the result, one after the drive letter and one before the number you want, so your number should be token 3

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, I think I will use

> for /F %%j in ('dir /B *.rar ^| find /C /V ""') do set count=%%j
>
> user135127

In this way I think also if  somethink in the name of the dir the result should remain always the same.

which is the difference between :

dir /B *.rar ^| find /C /V "" and

dir /B *.rar ^| find /C ".rar" ?

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f %a in ('dir "*.txt" ^| find "File(s)"') do set Count=%a
```

Gives

```
set Count=36
```

or you can use an arithmetic set and delayed environment variable expansion

```
set count=0
for %a in (*.txt) do @set /a Count=!Count!+ 1 > nul
echo %count%
```

gives

```
Count=36
```