# Execute python via batch based on some condition?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a python script which it is downloading some files, before executing the task, I want to know if directory is empty or if the number of files less than 5 then run the python otherwise just say the files already exist, how can I modify the batch code in order to apply this change.

```
@echo off
    .....

    :begin

    python.exe "%ScriptFolderPath%"\extractDAILYdata.py -u %UserName% -p %Password% -s %BirstSpace% -r %ATIBaseUrl% -sp %DailyLoadPath% -f "%LogPath%" -i %LogLevel% -l %LogFile%

    if %errorlevel%==0 goto bcsuccess

    :bcerror

    echo Task "%TaskName%" failed: %date% >> "%LogPath%\%LogFile%"
    exit /B %errorlevel%

    :bcsuccess

    echo Task "%TaskName%" succeeded: %date% >> "%LogPath%\%LogFile%"
```

Comment: If the python script is what is connecting to a remote system to get the files, then you would need to write something in your python code to check that. I don't see how a batch file could do it.

Comment: Add the check to the Python code, everything else will be ugly

Comment: I am learning batch and I really like to learn how can I do it with batch.

Comment: Are you trying to check a local directory or the remote directory that the python program is getting data from? [Get Number of files in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3814603/number-of-files-in-a-directory)

Comment: @Squashman  it's just a local directory.